# Whole line highlight in teal colour in visual studio code? Teal colour

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFqdL.jpg)The teal colour highlighted in visual studio code on whole line in the background of code, which is annoying me and my eyes. How to remove the colour on entire line.

I tried in YouTube and googling it but couldn't find answer. Please help me out

Comment: It would be better if you take a screenshot on the pc/mac instead of taking a photo on your phone and using that. Also, it would be much better if you put the photo directly into the question instead of making the viewers go to another link.

Comment: that color is different for each Theme

Answer (score 0):

[image]It looks like you have installed the 'error lens' extension in vs code, please uninstall it

Answer (score 0):

this is a dart analysis warning. either you clear the error by:

1. using `const` constructor on the widget, on this case is the MaterialApp, since you don't have any changed parameters on the widget:

```
...
  const MaterialApp(
    ...
  ),
...
```

or,

2. using VSCode's Quick Fixes and ignoring the errors, like so:
   [image]